# Safari 12 css animations not working well

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a list of elements to slide in one after the other when rendered into the page.

Everything works well in Chrome and Firefox, even in Safari 11 work well, but safari 12 is not doing the animation well.

As shown in the following image, all items should be aligned to the top when the animation is completed, but for some reason only in Safari 12, the items are randomly rendered. In addition to that, the mouse over on the button is off.

[image]

You can take a look at the problem here: https://codepen.io/crysfel/pen/GwoQxE (Make sure to open the link with safari 12)

I think the css is pretty standard:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(60px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.slide-in {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(60px);
  animation: slideIn ease 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 175ms;
}
```

And a simple javascript to animate the items one after the other:

```
function animateIn() {
  $('ul li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass('slide-in');
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).addClass('slide-in');
    }, 50 * index)
  })
}


$(() => {

  animateIn();

  $('#show').click(function() {
    animateIn();  
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

*I've fixed the issue*: It turns out all I had to do was removing `transform: translateY(60px);` from `slide-in`. Apparently safari was using that style at the end of the animation overwriting the final value. It's very weird, because visually looks wrong but the active zones and all are fine.

Comment: Hi @Crysfel did you find a fix to this issue? Currently trying to fix it also.

Comment: Yes!! It turns out all I had to do was removing `transform: translateY(60px);` from `slide-in`. Apparently safari was using that style at the end of the animation overwriting the final value. It's very weird, because visually looks wrong but the active zones and all are fine.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks @Crysfel that fixed my issue.

Comment: That's a really weird fix, because the animation-fill-mode: forwards should have applied the style from your to at the end of the animation...I wonder if Safari 12 has an issue with animation-fill-mode?

Comment: That's right, it should! And it does apply the correct styles in Chrome, Firefox and even Safari 11. This is a bug in Safary 12 only

Comment: Yes this is definitely a bug in Safari. Final animation styles are supposed to stay applied, that's kind of a major component to how they work. I'm actually pretty surprised that they released this regression.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a prefix to keyframes and animation for safari.  Use something like this:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(60px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(60px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.slide-in {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(60px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(60px);
  animation: slideIn ease 1;
  -webskit-animation: slideIn ease 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 175ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 175ms;
}
```

A helpful tool to use is [shouldiprefix.com](https://shouldiprefix.com)

Comment: Thanks! But Safari 12 already supports all the css above, the problem is something else :(